# help identifying fungi/virus on Agave americana

Tags: diseases

TL;DR I'm trying to identify a pathogen on my agave.

I have an *Agave americana* in my yard in New Orleans, LA.  It has generally grown vigorously, although it sometimes struggles during wet + cloudy spells.  For a while there was clearly an infection in the center whorl (meristem? where the leaves emerge from) that produced some brownish liquid and rot, and I thought the plant was a goner.  I did a little surgery and tlc on the plant, and it recovered and has continued to grow.

However, since then a few  interesting circular scars have emerged.  The plant seems to be fine, but I'm interested in identifying what this might be.  Not sure if it's a fungus or a virus, but I haven't seemed to find the correct combination of google search to find a convincing picture of the scars.

[image: fungus, virus or other?]

[image: second picture]

Comment: Looks like circular leaf miner damage. Need something systemic, but I hate to recommend stinky Malathion. However, for too-wet challenge in humid New Orleans, move it to a clay pot in a sandy cactus mix.

Comment: That makes sense, I can believe leaf miner.  I'm not too worried about trying to rehabilitate it, generally speaking it's growing ok. The plant is about 5 ft tall, so potting it would be a prickly business :-). Thanks for the help!